# I graduated from my master studies about 1.5 year ago. Could this affect my attempts for a PhD?

Tags: phd

I graduated from my master studies 1.5 year ago (almost). Could this gap affect my attempts for setting foot into a PhD?

I have to say that all that time I acquired 2 certifications in different languages as well as one professional certificate for advancing my programming capabilities.

I would like also to ask you if should I say (in a possible interview) the fact that I was offered a PhD position but for significant personal reasons that time, I had to reject it. It was pretty bad for me.

I appreciate any response

Best regards

Comment: The last 1.5 years has been, well, interesting for most people. Not knowing what one should do in the face of a global pandemic is going to be understood by most.

Comment: You might say where you are and what country/countries you intend to study in.

Answer (score 1):

This should not matter much. 1.5 years is not that long, and it means the biggest potential hurdle you face (your recommenders retiring or similar) is probably not a big issue.

You might have to explain (in your statement of purpose or in the interview) why you took 1.5 years off, though 1.5 years really is not that long so it might not come up.

Answer (score 0):

The certificates probably count for littlest in many places the gap shouldn't matter at all. Lots of people take a break. But make sure that you still have current contact with professors from your earlier studies - people who can support your application.

And you don't need to offer apologies for why you turned down an earlier offer.

Comment: Do you believe that should I say about past PhD offer or only if being asked?

Comment: Saying that you had to turn it down for personal reasons should be enough anywhere - though I don't know _everywhere_. But you have a right to keep personal things personal. Whether you mention it in the CV is up to you, but if you do, then tag it as 'declined for personal' reasons

Comment: Or a tag like 'personal reasons, since resolved' might be good to indicate it isn't an issue for the future.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As for my current applications, programs for which I apply don't require recommendation letters. I am asking because my Profs are a little bit frustrated from that time. Will I have any problem for these particular programs?

Comment: It seems unlikely if letters aren't required. And "frustrated" can also mean wishing for the best for you and sad that you haven't gotten along faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I, myself, has joined PhD almost 3 years after my masters and has been doing it till now, in Mathematics. In the mean time I qualified for PhD_fellowship_exam and also got a bachelor of Education (B.Ed.) course. So my answer to you is that you are not late. But you should have the strong motivations to spend 3-5 years approximately in PhD.